# Different results locally and in staging

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm using google custom search engine with a search engine that searches specific sites and excludes some patterns in these sites.
I'm testing the api locally and I receive 12 results. I test the same exact call in staging (`heroku us region`) and I receive 410 results.

Does google personalise the results when using a custom search engine?
If yes, how do I turn it off? If no, do you have any idea why am I seeing this difference?

**Update**

Ok I did a test. I issued the exact same request by using a proxy and not, and the results are different (vastly).

Now, the question is, can this behaviour be disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found it. By specifying the `userIp` param https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest it will force google to use the same behaviour regardless of location.